# SyndicationItem serialized with Atom10ItemFormatter returns empty output

Tags: c#, .net, atom-feed

```
private static string SerializeItem(SyndicationItem item)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Atom10ItemFormatter formatter = new Atom10ItemFormatter(item);
    formatter.WriteTo(XmlWriter.Create(builder));
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Returns empty string. Why? `item` is a valid atom entry received from the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XmlWriter is not being disposed of/flushed and so the output builder has not been written to.

The following example works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SyndicationFeed feed = null;

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds"))
    {
        feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    }

    foreach(var item in feed.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SerializeItem(item));
    }
}

private static string SerializeItem(SyndicationItem item)
{
    var output      = new StringBuilder();
    var formatter   = new Atom10ItemFormatter(item);

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output))
    {
        formatter.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
After you have mentioned I noticed a remark for XmlWriter class:
When you use the XmlWriter methods to output XML, the elements and attributes will not be written until you call the Close method. For example, if you are using the XmlWriter to populate an XmlDocument, until you close the XmlWriter, you will not be able to observe the written elements and attributes in the target document.